# Worklight Facebook Login Button not displaying on Android Emulator

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on Facebook Login in Worklight(demo appliction to check facebook integration) ,i have implemented Login Button using Facebook Javascript SDk here's my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
<!--
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
            -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
</head>

<body style="display: none;">
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into Facebook.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '721457581245356',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "js/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--application UI goes here-->
    Facebook Page

<div id="fb-root">

        <!--
          Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
          the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
          the FB.login() function when clicked.
        -->

            <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
            </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status"></div>

    <div class="fb-like" 
         data-share="true" 
         data-width="450"
         data-show-faces="true"
         style="padding-top: 10px;"></div>

</div>

    <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/messages.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run the application on Worklight Android Simulator the login button is displayed but on **Login Button click i get an error** what is this error ?
[image]

And now when i am trying to run the android project (created by worklight) on **Android Emulator** it does not display the Login Button 
[image]

is it related to re-direct url ? or call back url ?
i have tried googling a lot but nothing is working
what does that **ERROR** mean ?
can any1 help ?

Comment: What do you see in LogCat when you run in the Android Emulator?

Comment: Uncaught Exception: Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined at (compiled_code):41

Comment: What is this Error
**"Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."**
 kindly reply i am stuck here

Comment: That's a facebook error. follow the facebook instructions.

Comment: Did you try to google this error message? there are a ton of results.

Comment: yes i did ...and i am missing out something in the app setting on developer site where my app is registered ....
but what exactly i am not able to figure out ....
what should be the app URL ,Domain Url ...as i am doing FB integration on test application in worklight...
so which Url should i mention?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion to you is to use the Native Android SDK that Facebook provides.

If you are using 6.1 and below, you can use the [WL.NativePage.show](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.NativePage.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-20) API.
If you are using 6.2 and above, you can use the [SendAction](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html) API.

Using the above APIs you can invoke a new page (class) to which you will integrate the native Android SDK, which will enable you to display the Facebook Login page and/or use other options provided by Facebook.